# How to add different css for same class using css or javascript?(Edited)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Edited:Q1 is solved if possible then reply for Q2.

Q1)for example i have some html like that

```
<div class="toggle-menu-wrap">
    <div class="toggle-menu-wrap">
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="main-menu sidebar-menu subeffect-fadein-left">
            <li class="menu-item narrow">
                <div class="popup gotomenutop">
                    <ul class="sub-menu gotosubmenu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Main Demo</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Construction</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Hotel</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item narrow">
                <div class="popup gotomenutop">
                    <div class="popup gotomenutop">
                        <ul class="sub-menu gotosubmenu">
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Main Demo</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Construction</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Hotel</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item narrow">
                <div class="popup gotomenutop">
                    <div class="popup gotomenutop">
                        <ul class="sub-menu gotosubmenu">
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Main Demo</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Construction</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Hotel</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item narrow">
                <div class="popup gotomenutop">
                    <div class="popup gotomenutop">
                        <ul class="sub-menu gotosubmenu">
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Main Demo</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Construction</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Hotel</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i want to add css style for class gotomenutop with different top value..
like given below

```
.gotomenutop {
    top: 0px;
}
.gotomenutop {
    top: -42px;
}
.gotomenutop {
    top: -84px;
}
.gotomenutop {
    top: -126px;
}
```

you can clearly see that different between top value is `42` for `.gotomenutop`.
how can i achieve this ?? and
Q2)

> first gotosubmenu first li have "top" value:-5px
>
> first gotosubmenu second li have "top" value:-40px
>
> first gotosubmenu third li have "top" value:-75px
>
> first gotosubmenu fourth li have "top" value:-110px
> and and same thing repeat for second gotosubmenu first li
> how can i achieve this and this all thing generate dynamically..

JQuery and javascript any would be ok...for me..

Comment: So, essentially, the margin is doubled for each li, right? Will there be a fixed/maximum number of lis that you know upfront, or does it have to be dynamic?

Comment: @Connum the lis is dynamically generated its dont have fixed count..

Comment: Ok, then you'll either have to define as many CSS rules as you think will ever be needed, or use the jQuery approach!

Comment: You have accepted answer and now edited the question this renders answer meaningless. Better post a new question

Comment: @Satpal i know that...and i told you below but you not answered so i have to edit it...and if you have answer then give it otherwise leave it...ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use jquery, use  [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) with callback. In callback function set value of top relevant to index of element.

```
$(".gotomenutop").css("top", function(i){
    return i * -42;
});
```

---

**Update:**
For second question, you should loop through `.gotosubmenu` using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and in loop, iterate every `li` tag and add css to it using above code.

```
$(".gotosubmenu").each(function(){
  $(this).find("li").css("top", function(i){
    return (i * -35) - 5;
  });
});
```

Comment: i cant get it can you please explain it in depth..pls

Comment: @amreshsingh The code loop through `.gotomenutop` elements and add css for every of them. The `i` variable in function is index of element that start with 0. To better understanding see https://jsfiddle.net/3tc6pk68/

Comment: hay @Mohammad can you please Question i just edited it and can you please help with second part of ..pls..

Answer (score 6):

Use [`:nth-chlid()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class selector.

```
li:nth-child(1) > .gotomenutop {
  top: 0px;
}
li:nth-child(2) > .gotomenutop {
  top: -42px;
}
li:nth-child(3) > .gotomenutop {
  top: -84px;
}
li:nth-child(4) > .gotomenutop {
  top: -126px;
}
```

**Note:** Which is limited to a certain number of elements.

---

**UPDATE:** If there are a random number of elements then it would be better to go for jQuery. Use jQuery [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) method with a callback, within the callback first argument holds index and generates the property value based on the index.

```
$('.gotomenutop').css('top', function(i) {
  // generate the value
  return i * -42;
})
```

---

Or with pure Javascript by getting and iterating over the elements.

```
// get all elements and convert into array
// for older browser use - [].slice.call()
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.gotomenutop'))
  // iterate over the elements
  .forEach(function(ele, index) {
    // apply the style property
    ele.style.top = index * -42;
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend @Pranav answer, However here is jQuery option of using [`$.fn.css(propertyName, fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) method

```
$('.gotomenutop').css('top', function(index, x) {
  return -index * 42;
})
```

```js
$('.gotomenutop').css('top', function(index, x) {
  return -index * 42;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-menu-wrap">
  <div class="toggle-menu-wrap">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="main-menu sidebar-menu subeffect-fadein-left">
      <li class="menu-item narrow">
        <div class="popup gotomenutop">1</div>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item narrow">
        <div class="popup gotomenutop">2</div>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item narrow">
        <div class="popup gotomenutop">3</div>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item narrow">
        <div class="popup gotomenutop">4</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hay @Satpal is any way to reset index and caculation to start again after it leaves first gotomenutop class..

Comment: hay can you please help me with that because i have another set of <li> tag in gotomenutop <div> which have structure like
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children sub" data-cols="1">
 <ul class="sub-menu gotosubmenu">
<li class="menu-item"><a href="">Classic - Color</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="">Classic - Color</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
and i want do it same thing for each gotosubmenu but whenever it leaves first gotosubmenu then again start calculation from ZERO....